# Fiscal Year from Current Date

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSMS/SSRS2012 working on report to capture all hours worked in the current fiscal year, which for this purpose is Oct 1-Sep 30.

I'm looking for a case statement that says the following:
if the current month < 10 (october) then @FYStart = last year
if the current month >= 10 then @FYStart = current year

When I query `SELECT GETDATE()` here is the format: `2020-06-16 15:24:57.637`

I have tried the following, but it only half works.

`SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,(CAST(getdate() AS INT)))>09
    THEN YEAR(CAST(getdate() AS INT))
    ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,-1,(CAST(getdate() AS INT)))
    END`

The result from this gives me `2019-06-17 00:00:00.000` which is a step in the right direction, but if I change the month to a month that has already passed,

`SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,(CAST(getdate() AS INT)))>03
    THEN YEAR(CAST(getdate() AS INT))
    ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,-1,(CAST(getdate() AS INT)))
    END`

I get this result: `1905-07-14 00:00:00.000`

Something is obviously going wrong here but I'm not sure what exactly. I'm thinking it's something with the data types but I'm not sure what to check/where to start.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I gather, you are trying to isolate the year (as an integer) from today's date and store it in `@FYStart`. If today's date is before October, you want to assign it to last year, and if it's October or later, assign it to this year, correct?

If so, try this:

```
DECLARE @FYStart int
SET @FYStart = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) < 10
        THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) -- last year
    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())  -- this year
    END
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm overlooking something, is it not just something as simple as...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(getdate()) <10
        THEN YEAR(getdate()) -1
        ELSE YEAR(getdate())
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what @cpalmer had, the following will let you query data where a date column is **since the fiscal year start** based on the current date that the query is run.

This will allow the report / query to be non-static.

```
DECLARE @CurrentFiscalYearStart Date;
SET @CurrentFiscalYearStart = (
    SELECT CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) < 10
    THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) -- last year
    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())  -- this year
    END AS VARCHAR) +'-10-01' AS Date)
    )

SELECT @CurrentFiscalYearStart AS FiscalYearStart; -- example

SELECT TOP(100) * FROM Table WHERE DateColumn >= @CurrentFiscalYearStart ORDER BY DateColumn; -- example in query
```

**NOTE: replace the 10 in both places in the SQL with the month of the fiscal year for the company, etc.**

This returns a date for comparison, vs. a year integer.

Comment: Original post was a couple years ago, posting this as reference for others.